# can you make a responsive iframe if you have no control over the parent?

Tags: iframe, responsive-design

I have been trying to find a solution for creating a responsive iFrame. I have found quite some solutions, but they usually describe a situation where the person wanting to embed an iFrame has control over the parent page.

If I offer embed code that allows people to embed a certain webpage into their own page by means of an iFrame, how should I do that and make sure it is responsive, without any knowledge of the parent page it will be embedded in? In other words, can I manage to implement this from the code in the iFrame itself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can technically make the iframe responsive.. but I just don't see the point if the website you're pointing to isn't responsive. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uMbWP/1/

Resize the bottom right frame width to see.

I set the min-width to 320px, because that's as small as mobile devices usually go.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<iframe src="http://www.reddit.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    min-height:640px;
    min-width:320px;
}

iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:640px
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution is similar to the ones I already found, but your solution also assumes that I have control over the parent page.